# macro on proc export.

Tags: macros, sas

Hi I am creating a macro proc export after proc contents and here the code goes.

```
%macro cont(dataset_sheet, library );


proc contents data= &library .&dataset_sheet    out=&dataset_sheet 
;   run;

proc export data= &library . &dataset_sheet  outfile="C:\mapp.xls" 
dbms=excelcs replace; sheet="&dataset_sheet";run;
%mend;

%cont(dataset, my_lib);
```

and it works for proc contents but when I run both it says there is no library of that kind in the proc export statement... what is wrong here?

Comment: Are the extra spaces in the above in your code or are they introduced by copying/pasting?

Comment: they came from copy paste.
at &library.&dataset it is not taking the '.' so I gave a space after &library 
it ran for proc contents., but it is not doing it for export.

Comment: It is not recognising the dataset in the proc export statement.
it says work.my_lib.data doesnt exist., where as ,my_lib has to be a library and dataset should be the dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem likely arises from the fact that `.` is the macro variable terminator.  It is normally optional, but if it exists it is used; and thus in cases where the next character is actually supposed to be `.` it should be doubled.

As such, `&library.&dataset.` where `&library` = `WORK` and `&dataset` = `TEST` means you are asking for `WORKTEST`, not `WORK.TEST`.  You need a second period: `&library..&dataset` in this case.

Comment: I tried that Joe and it says 
ERROR: File work.dataset.DATA does not exist.

Comment: Then you probably don't have `&dataset` defined properly.

Answer (score 0):

Remove extra space after library name and include another "."

```
%macro cont(dataset_sheet, library );


proc contents data= &library..&dataset_sheet    out=&dataset_sheet 
;   run;

proc export data= &library..&dataset_sheet  outfile="C:\mapp.xls" 
dbms=excelcs replace; sheet="&dataset_sheet";run;
%mend;

%cont(dataset, my_lib);
```

Comment: it actually worked direclty... i removed the spaces and ran it.,
No need of any double period

Comment: You certainly need the double period - it should not work without it, unless you leave "&library" blank entirely (using WORK by default).